# How to handle in app purchase within a real-time multiplayer iOS game

Tags: ios, game-center, gamekit, multiplayer

This question is more about design and UX rather than programming. I don't find enough real world examples of what I want to do, so I need some guidance.

In my Game Center supported, real time, multiplayer game I want to offer some consumable purchases, at random times.
Both players compete on following basis:

- There are X assets available
- Both of them start at the same time occupying each asset
- When all X assets are taken, the player having max assets win.
- The number of players is constant: 2
- During any time of the gameplay, in app purchase is offered to any user, through which he can speed up the asset acquisition process.

The question is - when one players busies himself purchasing an in-app purchase, what should the other player do?

Should I enforce him to pause because another player is buying stuff?
What if the purchase didn't go through?

As one can see, I can't punish the purchasing user by allowing the non-purchasing player to continue while the purchasing is in progress.

What would be a fair-game policy and how would I achieve it?

**P.S.** I could well raise this question on some game forum, but I am afraid I don't know enough keywords to explain my problem. Maybe its a classic one but I don't know what to call it - so please bear with me and guide accordingly.

Comment: Sounds like a 'pay to win' game so how do you even define 'fair'

Comment: @Wain, good point. Is this allowed? If yes, have you known other games already doing that? Any matrix would be interesting.

Comment: You'd need to ask Apple if it's allowed. I guess other games allow you to buy equipment but it isn't consumable (and the system grades players to try to maintain a level playing field). You game at the moment doesn't sound fun to me as I wouldn't want to always be racing to buy to win...

Comment: Perhaps you could purchase "power ups" before the game began and use them during the game. Many games use this model. Some allow you to purchase specific abilities while others allow you to purchase in-game currency (gems/coins/donuts/whatever) that can be redeemed for abilities. Either way the actual in-app purchase happens outside of gameplay.

Comment: @Paulw11 +1 for that. If it's something to be purchased beforehand, does it make sense to make them non-consumable? Do power-ups fall into that category, I wonder?

Comment: That is really up to you depending on how your game works.  Something like an "extra shield" could be consumable - you use it once and it is consumed, then you need to purchase it again, or it could be an "upgrade" - say a permanent 10% increase in your shield, in which case it would be non-consumable.  Generally the "freemium" model tends to use consumable because people have to keep paying...